Projection on a countable union of linear subspace
For any natural number $n$, $V_n$ denotes a closed linear subspace of a $L_2(m)$ space, which is an Hilbert Space, where $m$ denotes a finite measure. Moreover $(V_n)$ is increasing, that is $V_n$ is a subspace of $V_{n+1}$ for any $n$. Denote by $P_n$ the orthogonal projection on $V_n$ and by $P_V$ the projection on the closure $V$ of the union of all the $V_n$. Is it true that $P_n$ converges to $P_V$ in the usual operator norm? Or does it converges just for some weaker notion of convergence? What conditions are required to ensure this?

No. If the subspaces are finite dimensional the projecors would be compact operators and  the norm limit of compact operators is a compact operator. If V is infinite dimensional the projection on V will not be compact.

This is just a very standard and basic fact in Hilbert space theory that the convergence happens in SOT and not in norm, and hardly a research-level question.

Do you have a response to the answer below?

We have a nondecreasing sequence $(V_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ of closed subspaces of a Hilbert space $(H,|\cdot|)$ with an inner product $\cdot$ and the orthoprojectors $P_n$ onto $V_n$. We also have the closure $V$ of $\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N} V_n$.
Let $D_n:=P_n-P_{n-1}$ for $n\in\Bbb N$, where $P_0:=0$. Take any $x\in H$. Then
$$|x|^2\ge|P_n x|^2=\sum_{k=1}^n|D_k x|^2,$$
so that $\sum_{k\in\Bbb N}|D_k x|^2\le|x|^2<\infty$. So, for any natural $m$ and $n$ such that $m<n$ we have
$$|P_n x-P_m x|^2=\sum_{k=m+1}^n|D_k x|^2\to0$$
as $m\to\infty$. So, there exists
$$P_\infty x:=\lim_{n\to\infty}P_n x.$$
If is easy to see that $P_\infty$ is an orthoprojector. Also, clearly
$$P_\infty H\subseteq V.$$
Also, $(P_\infty H)^\perp\subseteq V^\perp$. Indeed, otherwise there is some $h\in (P_\infty H)^\perp\setminus V^\perp$. So, $h\cdot v\ne0$ for some $v\in V$. So, $h\cdot v_n\ne0$ for some $n\in\Bbb N$ and some $v_n\in V_n$. But $h\cdot v_n=h\cdot(P_\infty v_n)=0$, since $h\in (P_\infty H)^\perp$. This contradiction proves that $(P_\infty H)^\perp\subseteq V^\perp$.
So,
$$P_\infty H=V.$$
So, the sequence $(P_n)$ converges to the orthoprojector $P_\infty$ onto $V$ in the strong operator topology.
However, in general the sequence $(P_n)$ does not converge in the operator norm, because $\|P_{n+1}-P_n\|=1$ unless $V_{n+1}=V_n$.
